# SwiftUI TabView's onChange not Triggered When Selecting Different Tabs

Tags: swiftui

I'm encountering an issue with SwiftUI's TabView where the onChange modifier is not being called when I select different tabs. I've implemented a TabView with dynamically generated tabs based on a dictionary of keys, but the onChange closure doesn't seem to fire when I switch between tabs.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```swift
struct FunctionCatalogContainer: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    @State private var selectedTabIndex = 0 // Track the selected tab index

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TopColorGradient(color: .cyan)
            TabView(selection: $selectedTabIndex) {
                ForEach(Array(functionPropsTypes.keys.sorted()), id: \.self) { key in
                    Text(key)
                        .tabItem {
                            Text(key)
                        }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedTabIndex) { newIndex, _ in
                let selectedKey = Array(functionPropsTypes.keys.sorted())[newIndex]
                sharedState.functionCategory = selectedKey
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite selecting different tabs in the TabView, the onChange closure doesn't get triggered, and the sharedState.functionCategory doesn't update accordingly.

I tried a different way without `onChange` pass parameter directly to child, but still not good, show always first child:

```
struct FunctionCatalog: View {
    @State var functionCategory: String
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    var body: some View {
        List {
            if let parameterSignatures = functionPropsTypes[functionCategory]
            {
                ForEach(Array(parameterSignatures.keys.sorted()), id: \.self) { key in
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Text(key)
                    }.onDrag {
                        resetDragProperties()
                        sharedState.newFunctionName = key
                        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "YourDraggedData" as NSItemProviderWriting)
                        return itemProvider
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(.vertical, 40)
    }
}

struct FunctionCatalogContainer: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    @State private var selectedTabIndex = 0 // Track the selected tab index
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TopColorGradient(color: .cyan)
            TabView(selection: $selectedTabIndex) {
                ForEach(Array(functionPropsTypes.keys.sorted()), id: \.self) { key in
                    FunctionCatalog(functionCategory: key)
                        .tabItem {
                            Text(key)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: usually `onChange` is for an external action not for updating state, if feel the need to do it usually it means the source of truth is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your selection change work, try this, for your first code question:

1. add a `.tag(key)` to your tabItems.
2. your `selectedTabIndex` must match the type of the `.tag`, in your case the type of `key` a `String`.

Also note, that you should have `.onChange(of: selectedTabIndex) { oldValue, newValue in ...}`

For your second example code, you don't use the `selectedTabIndex`,
which in any case should be of the same type of the key, a String.